# how to implement converse.js with Zentyal server 7.0

Tags: converse.js, zentyal

i am trying to test the full page test site, it logs in but then keeps spinning and displays nothing.

any help is very much appriciated

Sepp

on the converse website i clicked on the full page test link, entered my credentials
both username@FQDN and username@IP, both accept the login, but blank display with rotating symbol..
just keeps spinning